# Relative path for an image in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I want render PDF from Thymeleaf template. I have some issue with specifying path for the image that stored in `resources/static/images/writing.png`

```
<img th:src="@{/images/writing.png}" alt=""></img>
```

Code above works well if I open page at a web browser but it throws exception when I try process it with the TemplateEngine

```
Link base "/images/writing.png" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "TimetablePDF" - line 64, col 26)
```

I have an option to specify full path at src like `http://localhost/images/...` but I think its awful, I dont want do that.

So how can I specify it without hardcoding?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```html
 <img th:src="@{classpath:static/images/writing.png}" />
```

Comment: I have tried it earlier, it doesnt see classpath.
I get error `classpath:static/images/writing.png net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: @ALEX please share your code related to configuring thymeleaf as well.

Comment: I havent got any config for Thymeleaf. I will be glad if you share something that resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do:

Create a custom class overiding the method as below as suggested by Thymeleaf developers:

> This method can be overridden by any subclasses that want to change
> this behaviour (e.g. in order to avoid using the Servlet API for
> resolving context path or to allow context-relative URLs in non-web
> contexts).

```
public class CustomLinkBuilder extends StandardLinkBuilder {

  @Override
  protected String computeContextPath(
      final IExpressionContext context, final String base, final Map<String, Object> parameters) {

    if (context instanceof IWebContext) {
      return super.computeContextPath(context, base, parameters);
    }

    return "./app/src/main/resources/static"; //assuming css and images are here

  }
}
```

Add this new LinkBuilder while creating template engine, e.g.:

```
    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine springTemplateEngine(){
        final TemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.setLinkBuilder(linkBuilder());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    ...

    private ILinkBuilder linkBuilder(){
        return new CustomLinkBuilder();
    }
```

I use the same engine to resolve to html pages (from WebContext) as well as resolving to string (from Context) with consequent converting to pdf. So this will be correctly rendered in both cases:

```
<head>
  ...

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/cat_wanted.css}">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR** Try to use Server-relative URLs: `@{~/` Like that: `<img th:src="@{~/images/writing.png}" alt=""></img>`.

**More information** about Server-relative URLs you can find here:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

**My issue**
I also had an issue with specifying the relative path for the image with the Thymleaf `th:src` tag.
I wanted to add a navbar logo picture for my web app:

```
    <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img th:src="@{images/favicon-32x32.png}" alt="Logo" width="30" height="24"/>
    </a>
```

**Problem:** 
`/profiles` endpoint used: `http://localhost:8080/images/favicon-32x32.png` 
`/profiles/2` endpoint used     `http://localhost:8080/profiles/images/favicon-32x32.png`

**My solution:**
I changed the image source to `th:src="@{~/images/favicon-32x32.png}"`

 And now all endpoints use `http://localhost:8080/images/favicon-32x32.png`