# CSS var() function does not work in Thymeleaf template to PDF

Tags: java, css, thymeleaf

I'm currently trying to create a report in PDF and am currently trying to use Thymeleaf to create an HTML template which I then try to convert to a PDF using flyingsaucer. It's working fairly well except, for some reason, I can declare all the CSS variables I like, the stylesheet won't actually use the colors stored in the variables when using the CSS `var()` function. A little example:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
  <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.22</version>
</dependency>
```

**template.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link th:href="@{/css/report.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="document-titles">
        <h1 class="document-title">Baking report</h1><br />
        <h2 class="document-date">September 2023</h2><br />
        <h3 class="document-project-name">Project name: cake</h3>
    </div>

    <h1>Test h1</h1>
    <h1>Test h1b (should be on next page (and it is!))</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <li>Cake</li>
        <li>Pie</li>
    </ol>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eggs</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>€4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Flour</td>
            <td>300 gr</td>
            <td>€1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**report.css**

```css
:root {
    /* Colors */
    --blue: #00a8dc;
    --grey: #9badbf;
    --text-black: #212529;
    --white: #fff;
}

@page {
    size: a4;
    orientation: portrait;
}

@page:first {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/report-cover.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    page-break-before: always;
    color: var(--blue); /* THIS IS COMPLETELY IGNORED; H1 REMAINS DEFAULT BLACK */
}

h1.document-title, h2.document-date, h3.document-project-name {
    page-break-before: avoid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**PdfProofOfConcept.java**

```java
package com.acme.reports;

import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.context.IExpressionContext;
import org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

public class PdfProofOfConcept {

    // https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-generate-pdf
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String template = parseThymeleafTemplate();
        generatePdfFromHtml(template);
    }

    private static void generatePdfFromHtml(String html) throws IOException {
        String outputFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "thymeleaf_report.pdf";
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFolder);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);

        outputStream.close();
    }

    private static String parseThymeleafTemplate() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        htmlTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        htmlTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver);
        templateEngine.setLinkBuilder(new CustomLinkBuilder());

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("secretIngredient", "Chocolate chips");

        return templateEngine.process("templates/report/thymeleaf_report", context);
    }

}

// Needed for using relative links in an offline setting (e.g. without a webserver)
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/74511450
class CustomLinkBuilder extends StandardLinkBuilder {
    @Override
    protected String computeContextPath(IExpressionContext context, String base, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        return "./src/main/resources/static";
    }
}
```

As the final bit of code shows, I ran into an issue where loading the stylesheet in the HTML didn't work because Thymeleaf expected it to be served from a `HttpServletRequest` whereas there is not webserver running in my case, so resources referenced and consumed (such as stylesheet, javascript and images) need to have a custom link built as it's not served from a webserver. (Hence the `CustomLinkBuilder`.) I'm thinking maybe something similar here is happening for the css `var()` function where normally the necessary CSS preprocessing happens in a browser or on a server. Am I correct and if so, how do I build my own preprocessor? (At least for the `var()` function.) Or is there another explanation as to why native CSS functions do not work with Thymeleaf?